# javascript function with if else statements ignore return true/false

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a PHP form which is being submitted with `isset($_POST[])`. I wrote a js function which runs some code with `if-else` which should `return true/false` but it's not and the form is getting submitted regardless.

I've tried using `e.preventDefault()` but that hasn't worked for me either. I also tried putting the true/false in a var as so `out = true/false` (Of course I put them in different var as for if and else), and then tried returning them as `return out`. 
Code for true/false in var -

```
function submitFunc(a, b) {
   if (a >= b) {
        alert("*Duration cannot be greater than Quoted Hours");
        out = false;
    }       
    else {
        out = true;
    }   
    window.location = "add_working_details.php";
    return out;

}
```

Original Code  -

```
function submitFunc(a, b) {

    if (a >= b) {
        alert("*Duration cannot be greater than Quoted Hours");
        // event.preventDefault();
        //out = false;
        return false;
                window.location = "add_working_details.php";
    }       
    else {
        // out = true;
        return true;
    }   
    //return out;
    // window.location = "add_working_details.php";
}
```

The AJAX function-

```
$("#submit").click(function(){//comparing the total quoted hours with duration of time selected         
        ticket_id = $('#ticket_no').val();
        total_hours = $('#total_hours').val(); 

        var user_dur, ud, th;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'comp_time.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {ticket_id: ticket_id, total_hours: total_hours} ,
            success: function (response) {
                // console.log("response", response);
                var resp = response;
                user_dur = $('#time_duration').text();
                ud = compare_time(user_dur); //user duration
                th = Number(resp); //total quoted hours

                submitFunc(ud, th);
            }

        }); 
    });
```

So I believe that returning `false` should stop the form from submitting and then with the `window.location` it should redirect to the page I want but it's not doing so. 
Please correct me if my logic is wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: How and where is the above code called? What are `a` and `b`? What do they contain and where do they come from? Also, since you have window.location after the return statement, that line will never be executed. Nothing after a return statement will be executed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The ```submitFunc``` is called inside an AJAX success method and that works, I just need to break the form from submitting. I see, I'll out the window.location before the return statement

Comment: _"The submitFunc is called inside an AJAX success method and that works"_ - Please show us that code as well. The above code on it's own isn't enough for us to know what actually happens.

Comment: Just updated the question with the ajax method. Sorry about that, I didn't want to unnecessarily make the post longer than required.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. What exactly is your `submtFunc()` suppose to do? Right now, you're posting the form using ajax. When that's done and you got a response, you call your `submitFunc()` but are completely ignoring the response of that function? Please explain what the expected flow here should be. Also, we still have no clue what any of your variables contains. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You setting of window.location after the return statement will never get executed.

Comment: We have a form. That form is getting submitted. The AJAX function is getting some values and passing it into the ```submitFunc```. The ```submitFunc``` is taking those values, comparing them with if-else and accordingly returning true/false. The problem is that false is not being returned and the form is still being submitted. Hope I cleared it up

Comment: _"and the form is still being submitted"_ - How would `submitFunc()` be able to stop the execution of the form if you placed it in the success callback? The success callback is called _after_ the form was submitted and can't stop what's already happened from happening. You can't put it before the form is submitted either, since you're using the response in that function.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Wont ```return false``` be able to stop it from submitting?

Comment: Only if that function can travel backwards in time, since you call it _after_ the form already has been submitted and you got a response . If you want to stop the form from submitting, you need to call that function _before_ the ajax request and actually _check_ the response of the function.

Comment: why not just move the comparison into the ajax func: if(ud >= th){window.location...}

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I see. The problem was probably with my understanding here. Thanks for the response, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First your function should prevent the submit regardless of the event outcome

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```

second you need to remove the returns from your function, they don't affect you click event

```
function submitFunc(a, b) {

    if (a >= b) {
        alert("*Duration cannot be greater than Quoted Hours");       
    } else {
       window.location = "add_working_details.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for me. the code im working on is really big, tried doing what you suggested but it interfered with some other stuff.

Comment: what other stuff besides the ajax call and the function you have?how does it interfere?

Comment: i have a datepicker which, when i implemented your code, does not work

Comment: what has a datepicker got to do with a form submit?how does it affect it ?

Comment: it didnt work when i put your code in, anyway i scrapped it and am trying something else. thanks for the response tho

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
   if (submitFunc(1, 2)) {
   $.ajax({});
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```